# how to create entire draggable website in jQuery

Tags: jquery, parallax

I'm planning to create a draggable website in jQuery. Any idea how exactly can I achieve this and what jQuery is used. Below is the example:
http://mordillo.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use a Jquery Plugin for DRAGGABLE BACKGROUND which you can find [HERE](https://github.com/kentor/jquery-draggable-background)

The Demo of this can be seen [HERE](http://kentor.me/jquery-draggable-background/)

Rest you can use PARALLAX EFFECT for further animations, this Parallax effect can be found [ON THIS PAGE](http://stephband.info/jparallax/)
These are the major resources that can help you build the desired website.
Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot..what about jquery.kinetic.whats difference between both of them.and can i have parallax scrolling multidirectional this way http://www.jacquico.com

Comment: Well Yes Jquery Kinetic is also an option, see there are multiple Jquery Plugins but I think the one I mentioned is SMOOTHER, however if you are comfortable with KINETIC, then go with that only.
And YES< YOU CAN HAVE PARALLAX FOR MULTIPLE DIRECTIONS.

Comment: And  for the Scrolling Background you can use : 
http://www.jqueryrain.com/2013/06/jquery-draggable-background/

Here you can set them as  Background (Width : 100% and Height : 100%)


And if you want infinite awesome Parallax, you can use http://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/  .. Just Click on the "i" Button at the center and you can download it. This is definitely going to Help.

And just for something more,(even though not what you want but hope it can be helpful) I think you may also consider is :
http://www.queness.com/post/2607/create-background-scrolling-effect-with-jquery

Comment: Your welcome, I would appreciate if you SELECT my answer as well.. hehe.. !!